# wp admin put categories in top-level menu

Tags: php, wordpress, wp-admin

Is there a way to move categories menu in wp admin to top-level?

By default they are located in posts sub menu.

I know that I can add another CPT and use it as a category, but I would like to know if it can be done like this: ˇ

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use this plugin to rearrange admin menu it is very helpfull.

https://wordpress.org/plugins/admin-menu-editor/

1) After installing go to Settings->Menu Editor

2) Create new menu and set Target page to Posts->Categories